# How do I remove "Unsubscribe From This List", but keep "Manage Email Preferences" link in e-mail from Sendgrid?

Tags: python, twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api, sendgrid-api-v3

I've previously set `asm_group_id` and `asm_groups_to_display` in my Python code, which create `Unsubscribe From This List` and `Manage Email Preferences` links in my e-mails.

I've noticed that some of the customers use antivirus solutions, which automatically click on every link in the e-mail and `Unsubscribe From This List` unsubscribes them straight away. Is there a way to remove this link programmatically, but keep the other one?

Or my only option is to edit my template?

Comment: What do you have in your template at the moment that renders the unsubscribe links?

Comment: @philnash I didn't have any special tags in template, in the end I just kept one required tag

Comment: Not sure what you are saying there. Have you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I came up against a similar issue using Campaigns within SendGrid, after working with the Twilio team it turns out using Single Sends and a Code Block (in the email designer) for the Unsubscription is the solution.

It will probably work for you as well if you are generating your comms all through code, this is what I used in the end:

```
<div style="width: 100%; padding: 18px 0;">
    <p style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;text-align: center">{{Sender_Name}}</p>
    <p style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;text-align: center">{{Sender_Address}}, {{Sender_City}}</p>
    <p style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:20px;text-align: center;"><a style="color: #444444;" href={{{unsubscribe_preferences}}}>Unsubscribe</a></p>
</div>
```

It results in only the Unsubscribe Preferences link which does not fall foul of the malware scanners that some organisations may use which unsubscribes in a single click.

Hope it helps you :)